# If on .focusout form contains no value, revert to original value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my `<input.../>` fields to go blank on focus, and if on focus out they're still blank, revert them to their original values.

I would've thought this would work, but apparently not:

```
$('input').focus( function() {
    var init_value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
});

$('input').focusout( function() {
    var new_value = $(this).val();

    if(new_value == "") {
        $(this).val(init_value);
    }
});
```

Any alterations/advice to get it working would be most appreciated ;)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute as a first option.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#placeholder

With jQuery, you could modify your original script like this:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});

$('input').focusout(function() {
   if($(this).val('')){
       $(this).val('Enter something');  
   }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8bJcQ/

**EDIT**

Here is a revised script to deal with the situation as mentioned in your comment:

> As for the jQuery option, that simply wouldn't do as it needs the
>   original value= value. I have perhaps 8 different text fields, the
>   instructions for which are the value, e.g. "Enter your email address",
>   "Enter your url", etc :(.

```
$('input').each(function(){

    var a = $(this).attr('value');

    $(this).focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });

    $(this).focusout(function() {
       if($(this).val('')){
           $(this).val(a);  
       }
    });

});
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8bJcQ/3/

Comment: Thanks for the idea and reference, I couldn't infer however from the article whether or not on the event of focusing out - without a value, it would originate back to the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: It will @Pixelatron.  See also my edit with the revised script.

Comment: As for the jQuery option, that simply wouldn't do as it needs the original `value=` value. I have perhaps 8 different text fields, the instructions for which are the value, e.g. "Enter your email address", "Enter your url", etc :(. Thanks though. EDIT: As for the HTML5 option that's great. This is a purely standards compliant build, so HTML5 will be fine (I should really read the full spec!).

Comment: And then adding one of the many already existing and tested jQuery hint plugins, as a second option.

Comment: @Pixelatron.  Yes, HTML5 is great!  I've revised the script to work in your needed solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier method of doing this assuming a modern browser is used. Simply add the attribute `placeholder="some text"` and the browser will handle all this for you. If you must support older browsers, try this:

```
var init_value;

$('input').focus( function() {
    init_value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
});

$('input').blur( function() {
    var new_value = $(this).val();

    if(new_value == "") {
        $(this).val(init_value);
    }
});
```

Your problem was the scope of `init_value`. You defined it inside an anonymous function, and could not access that value from a second anonymous function. To fix this you simply need to define `init_value` outside the scope of each event handler.

Also notice how I used `.blur()` instead of `.focusout()`. [The jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) explains the difference between the two.